# .htaccess - virtual subdomain as address to file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an address:

> http://referendum24.pl/referendum.php?id=**1389912771-przykladowe-referendum**

But I want to do redirect using an `.htaccess` for above given page was available at address:

> http://**1389912771-przykladowe-referendum**.referendum24.pl/

`$_GET['id']` is generated automatically.
Pages like the one shown above will be a lot, so it was nice to that command was universal.

Comment: is your question about "how to make the redirection" or "how to set several subdomain" ?

Comment: how to make redirection for automatically generated pages as the example above my friend :)

Comment: Seems rather clumsy. Wouldn't an SEO-format of `http://referendum.pl/referendum/1389912771-przykladowe` have been much cleaner? You might even run the risk that your server/Apache will reject the URL because the subdomain doesn't really exist, even before it gets to .htaccess.

Comment: Maybe u have right... it actually does not look nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^referendum24\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+referendum\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.%{HTTP_HOST}/? [R=302,L]
```

#### UPDATE:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.(referendum24\.pl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /referendum.php?id=%1 [L]
```

Comment: I dont know why, but that isnt work... Address: http://1389912771-przykladowe-referendum.referendum24.pl/ opens my index.php page.

Comment: Yes it will open index page since you wanted target URI as `http://1389912771-przykladowe-referendum.referendum24.pl/` and that is what it is showing in your browser.

Comment: or may be try rule in UPDATE section.

Comment: It is very close :) Redirected address can be stay the same ?
I mean, address: http://1389912771-przykladowe-referendum.referendum24.pl/ does not change for this: http://referendum24.pl/referendum.php?id=1389912771-przykladowe-referendum after redirect

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the apache rewrite module, you can use php :

referendum.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  header('Location: http://'.$id.'.refrendum24.pl');
  exit;
}
```

You can optionnaly add HTTP 301 response code.